# How can I copy all content in a <p> element omitting <span> tags but not their content

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```html
<div>
  <p><span class="selected-for-presentation">This is a <u><em><strong>very cool</strong></em></u> sentence...</span></p>
  <p>This is a <u><em><strong><span class="selected-for-presentation">very</span> cool</strong></em></u> sentence...</p>
</div>
```

and I am trying to write some XSLT that copies the full content of the paragraphs omitting the `<span>` tags but not their content. So the result should look something like this:

```html
<div>
  <p>This is a <u><em><strong>very cool</strong></em></u> sentence...</p>
  <p>This is a <u><em><strong>very cool</strong></em></u> sentence...</p>
</div>
```

This is my XSLT so far, which works for the first paragraph but not the second one:

```xml
<xsl:template match="p">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy_span_content"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="strong" mode="copy_span_content">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy_span_content"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="em" mode="copy_span_content">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy_span_content"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="u" mode="copy_span_content">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy_span_content"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span" mode="copy_span_content">
  <xsl:copy-of select="./node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler approach if you just want to remove the `span` and keep everything else, that is to use the [Identity Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to handle copying everything, and have an overriding template to skip over the `span` but carry on processing its children.

Try this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="span">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion from Tim C ([see below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55653446/8065825)) I came up with a solution that works perfectly. I couldn't keep it as simple as the suggestion since the HTML file I'm working with is more complex than the extract I provided and my XSLT file is imported into a larger one and I don't want the Identity Template to apply to other elements.

The solution I came up with:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="p[descendant::span]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy_without_span_tags"/>
        <!-- There is more stuff that goes in here in my actual template.-->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="copy_without_span_tags">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy_without_span_tags"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span" mode="copy_without_span_tags">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```